# Why is my Julia program using so much memory?

Tags: julia

According to `top`, my Julia program addresses 14.5 GB of memory (the "VIRT" column in the output of `top`) and it's size in physical memory is 7.5 GB (the "RES" column). But when I insert calls to `whos()` in my program, only about 100 MB of memory is accounted for:

```
                ArrayViews    190 KB     Module
                      Base  32427 KB     Module
                     Blosc     38 KB     Module
                  Calculus    178 KB     Module
                   Celeste   4034 KB     Module
                    Compat    126 KB     Module
                      Core   3268 KB     Module
                       DOC   1241 bytes  ASCIIString
                DataArrays    936 KB     Module
                DataFrames   1817 KB     Module
             Distributions   1245 KB     Module
                    DocOpt    221 KB     Module
                    Docile    420 KB     Module
               DualNumbers     59 KB     Module
                    FITSIO    971 KB     Module
                    FileIO    592 KB     Module
               ForwardDiff    304 KB     Module
                      GZip    588 KB     Module
                      HDF5   2698 KB     Module
                       JLD    335 KB     Module
                   Logging    103 KB     Module
                      Main  46514 KB     Module
                   NaNMath    121 KB     Module
                     Optim    475 KB     Module
                    PDMats    113 KB     Module
                  Reexport   3748 bytes  Module
         SortingAlgorithms     41 KB     Module
                 StatsBase    706 KB     Module
                 StatsFuns    289 KB     Module
                       WCS     78 KB     Module
                      main   8665 bytes  Function
```

How can I figure out what data structures are using up all the memory? Or why isn't unreferenced memory getting freed? (I'm even explicitly calling `gc()` sometimes.)

Comment: Julia won't track memories that allocated in `ccall`, which is widely used by libraries. Unfortunately, these memory also cannot be collected automatically by `gc()`. (But libraries should free them when their data structures `gc()`ed.)

Comment: Another data structure that isn't accounted for in `whos` is the method cache of all the JIT'ed code.  It's very difficult to say what's going on here without the code.

Comment: Note that `whos` was replaced by `varinfo` in Julia 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the limitations of `whos` mentioned by Matt B. and 张实唯, vectors in Julia are prone to being underreported in `whos`. Each vector takes about 80 bytes of space in total for the header and vector boxed object (on a 64-bit system), but this space is not counted by `whos` and can definitely add up.

For instance,

```
julia> module Test
           v = [[] for _ in 1:10000]
       end
Test

julia> whos(Test)
                          Test     80 KB     Module
```

This 80 KB is a substantial underestimate of how much memory `Test` is really using — it is about an order of magnitude off. So check for a large number of small vectors being created in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to profile your code and obtain a detailed analysis of where memory is allocated in your program the Julia manual has extensive documentation at
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/profile/#Memory-allocation-analysis on profiling your code. If you follow these steps you can identify hotspots in your code where a lot of allocations occur. You can also use `@time` macro, however, if you don't a priori know where allocations occur in your code it may be more difficult to pin down where you should place the macro to figure out where allocations occur.